# Creating a "list" of dataframes that can be passed to a function

Tags: r

I want to apply a function to multiple dataframes.
The question has been answered multiple times on Stackoverflow, e.g. [Apply a function to each data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791760/apply-a-function-to-each-data-frame) or [applying a function for a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954538/applying-a-function-for-a-list-of-dataframes).
However, I have a slightly different (beginner's) problem while creating a list of dataframes that can pass dataframes to the function.

I created a function

```
drawmyplot <- function(x){
variable <-x
aggregate(variable$c1, by=list(variable$c2, variable$c3), FUN=sum)
....
}
```

I call the function with a for loop

```
for (i in list_of_dataframes){
drawplot(i)
}
```

I have a list of dataframes

```
list_of_dataframes<-list("df_1","df_2")
```

When I run the script, I get the error

```
Error in variable$c1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

As far as I understand, I create a list with one vector and I don't pass any of my dataframes to the function.
How can I apply a function to every dataset of a number of dataframes df_1, df_2, df_3,.., df_n in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you have a list of strings:

```
list_of_dataframes<-list("df_1","df_2")
```

If you want a list of dataframes use

```
list_of_dataframes<-list(df_1,df_2)
```

Comment: thx, this was responsible for the warning. I had also tried your suggestion before, and when I run the script, I don't get an error - but nothing happens when the function is running. When I call the function directly `drawmyplot(df_1)`, the function does exactly what it is supposed to do. do you have any idea?

Comment: I would put a print statement inside the function drawmyplot to see what's going on.  If you call your function from the loop, you should see it printing out the same stuff when you were calling each dataframe individually.